# React-native RNCallkeep.displayIncomingCall not working in Android when App is in killed mode

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make a app using audio video call feature. I have used the React-native-callkeep to inform the reciever about the call.
flow of the call goes like : when caller hit the call initiate button  reciever gets an FCM Push notification with data to join the Room

I want to awake the reciever screen when reciever App is in killed state. for which I'm using react-native-callkeep.
I'm calling displayIncomingCall() function to awake the screen it is working fine in IOS but not working in Android when App is in killed state.

```
//function to call the incoming call screen

export const Display = async (uuid, handle, localizedCallerName) => {
  RNCallKeep.displayIncomingCall(uuid, handle, localizedCallerName);
};
// inside index.js
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (data) => {
  if (data.data?.description == "audio" || data.data?.description == "video") {
    Platform.OS == "android"
      ? Display(
          "11edc52b-2918-4d71-9058-f7285e29d894",
          "Shadowz Calling",
          data?.data?.sent_by_name
        )
      : Display(
          "11edc52b-2918-4d71-9058-f7285e29d894",
          "Shadowz Calling",
          data?.data?.sent_by_name,
          "number",
          "false"
        );
  }
});
```

Comment: what type of FCM notification you are sending? data or notification type ? Be more specific on your question.At least provide the code and your notification payload that you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a **data type** firebase notification to trigger `BackgroundMessageHandler`.You cannot snd it by firebase console and you have to send a POST request to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` api.sample code added below.

```
const sendPush = async () => {
let data = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    to: '<device token>',
    priority: 'high',
    data: {
      description:"audio"// your data here
    },
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization:
      '<server key>',//copy this from your project in firebase console
  },
};
return fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', data)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log('FCM Response---', json));

};
```

You can test this using postman also.

Read more about FCM notification types - https://www.javatpoint.com/firebase-types-of-message